# Convert JSON records in PostgreSQL into a Table

Tags: json, postgresql, tableau-api

I have a table_1 in PostgreSQL with column_1 and several records in the column containing a nested json with the following structure:

```
{"parent_1": {
    "child_1": [10.477058081076123, 12.570963520289965, 11.74866851427825],
    "child_2": [14.174190848828983, 19.3920283059595, 17.6712937162821]
},
"parent_2": {
    "child_1_1": [24.100638151071383, 28.544734824158617, 26.83283592992511],
    "child_1_2": [14.466083025027984, 34.788137217452125, 19.018732389073737]
} }
```

I want to convert the json record into another table so that I can import it as a customSQL including the arrays into Tableau.

EDIT 1:

This is the query I am trying:

```
 SELECT * , table_1.column_1 -> 'parent_1' ->  json_object_keys((table_1.column1 ->> 'parent_1')::json) FROM  public.table_1
```

EDIT 2:

As an output I would like to get a Table per Parent to be read as such in Tableau. In each table I would like to have:

Table: parent_1

```
Childs  | Value
----------------------------
child_1   | 10.477058081076123
child_1   | 12.570963520289965
child_1   | 11.74866851427825
child_2   | 14.174190848828983
child_2   | 19.3920283059595
child_2   | 17.6712937162821
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first unnest the inner structure of each "parent", and then unnest the array for each element.

For the first table you could do something like this:

```
create table parent_1
as
select p.k as child, e.v as value
from table_1
     cross join lateral jsonb_each(column_1 -> 'parent_1') as p(k,v)
     cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(p.v) as e(v);
```

To do the same thing for the second table, replace the `column_1 -> 'parent_1'` with `column_1 -> 'parent_2'`